# Export/import libre office keyboard shortcuts

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, key-bindings, libreoffice

Libre Office lacks some of the keyboard shortcuts im used to from other programs. 
I would like to avoid reassigning keyboard keys each time im on a new system and also share my shortcuts with others.

Is there a way to import/export keyboard shortcuts for Libre Office?

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in way.

You can locate the definitions in the user profile directory, file `registrymodifications.xcu`

**Make a backup!**

Extract the lines starting with `<item oor:path="/org.openoffice.Office.Accelerators/`

Insert them into of a new installation.**

```
**not tested by me, as I usually copy the whole registry file - which worked up to now
```